# Clicking links on just opened pages using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, click, element

I have managed to open a web page with

```
var win = window.open("http://url.com", '_blank');
```

Now I want to find and click a link on that page. But

```
var link = win.document.getElementByClass("");
```

won't find anything.

How can I find and click such a link?
I only know its (unique) "class", but no ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross-Origin rules will not allow you to access the DOM of another window. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a CORS issue. Unless `url.com` is the same url as the one where you launched this code from, CORS will prevent you from seeing any content of the other page.

**EDIT**

`.getElementByClass` is not a real Javascript function. You're looking for `.getElementsByClassName`.